# Very simple application for managing a list of tasks and associating iCal events

Tags: macos, calendar, gtd

I have a list of tasks in a plan text file and I would like to create some very simple mac application where I can assign each task to an iCal event with an associated date, and the possibility to change later that date or delete associated event. Everything will be in my computer.

I do not know where can I start from or even if AppleScript would be useful here, any help?